# Scaled PDDocument from PDF

Tags: java, pdf

I created a `org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument` by reading in another PDF from some file.

The created new PDDocument consists only of the page(s) of the original one. Fine.

Now, because I want to add a header and footer line which would disturb the design, I want to `scale down` the read PDF say to `80%` and put it into the `middle of the new page`. I used the following code right now:

```
private static PDDocument createNewPDDocument4Doc_v1(PDDocument pdDoc) {
    PDDocument outputDoc = new PDDocument();
    int pageCount = pdDoc.getNumberOfPages();
    for (int p = 0; p < pageCount; p++) {
        PDPage oldPage = pdDoc.getPage(p);
        // PDPage newPage = new PDPage();
        outputDoc.addPage(oldPage);

        PDRectangle oldMediaBox = oldPage.getMediaBox();
        PDRectangle bleedBox = oldPage.getBleedBox();
        PDRectangle cropBox = oldPage.getCropBox();

        float lowerLeftX = oldMediaBox.getLowerLeftX();
        float lowerLeftY = oldMediaBox.getLowerLeftY();
        float upperRightX = oldMediaBox.getUpperRightX();
        float upperRightY = oldMediaBox.getUpperRightY();
        float height = oldMediaBox.getHeight();
        float width = oldMediaBox.getWidth();

        float shrinkPoints = 100f;

        float newLowerLeftX = lowerLeftX + shrinkPoints;
        float newLowerLeftY = lowerLeftY + shrinkPoints;
        float newUpperRightX = upperRightX - shrinkPoints;
        float newUpperRightY = upperRightY - shrinkPoints;

        /* This did not help either:
        oldMediaBox.setLowerLeftX(newLowerLeftX);
        oldMediaBox.setLowerLeftY(newLowerLeftY);
        oldMediaBox.setUpperRightX(newUpperRightX);
        oldMediaBox.setUpperRightY(newUpperRightY);

        bleedBox.setLowerLeftX(newLowerLeftX);
        bleedBox.setLowerLeftY(newLowerLeftY);
        bleedBox.setUpperRightX(newUpperRightX);
        bleedBox.setUpperRightY(newUpperRightY);

        cropBox.setLowerLeftX(newLowerLeftX);
        cropBox.setLowerLeftY(newLowerLeftY);
        cropBox.setUpperRightX(newUpperRightX);
        cropBox.setUpperRightY(newUpperRightY);
        */ 
        try (PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(outputDoc, oldPage, AppendMode.PREPEND, false)) {
            
            cs.saveGraphicsState();
            cs.transform(Matrix.getScaleInstance(DEFAULT_IMAGE_SCALING_SIZE, DEFAULT_IMAGE_SCALING_SIZE));
            cs.saveGraphicsState();
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try (PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(outputDoc, oldPage, AppendMode.APPEND, true)) {
            cs.restoreGraphicsState();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        outputDoc.addPage(oldPage);
    }
    return outputDoc;
}
```

But unfortunately that does not do the trick.

The original PDF is indeed shrinked to  `DEFAULT_IMAGE_SCALING_SIZE = 0.80f`

But placed in the lower left corner of my new PDDocument. I could get around this by converting the original PDF into an (scaled) image and place that one into the middle of the page.

But this is not what I want because the final PDF would have a much more increased size and the highlightings in the original PDF would be lossed.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You scale by `DEFAULT_IMAGE_SCALING_SIZE`. As usually (not always!) the origin of the page coordinate system is in the lower left of the page, this scaling also usually pulls the content towards the lower left. Thus, you must combine the scaling with a translation that makes the center of the page a fix point of the whole operation. Furthermore, you apply two `saveGraphicsState` calls but only one `restoreGraphicsState` call. Thus, you create unbalanced calls. This strictly speaking is invalid.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So how would I to this translation then? I admit that I removed the second call to "restoreGraphicsState" as it seemed to have no effect ...

Comment: *"I admit that I removed the second call to "restoreGraphicsState" as it seemed to have no effect ..."* - well, the `saveGraphicsState` and `restoreGraphicsState` must balance. (PDF viewers often won't complain but unbalanced calls are likely to cause errors when further processing the PDFs.) Actually you don't need any of them at all, or just one save at the very start and one restore at the end.

Comment: Ok, I managed to include the "movement" of the new scalled page by using these lines instead of the "getScaleInstance" method:
...
Matrix matrix = new Matrix(DEFAULT_IMAGE_SCALING_SIZE, 0, 0, DEFAULT_IMAGE_SCALING_SIZE, newLowerLeftX, newLowerLeftY);
cs.transform(matrix);
...
Ok, that was step1... Now the "markuped" text on the page must also be transformed.. Where in the page Dictionary is this information kept? Does someone know?

Comment: The `PDPage` method `getAnnotations` will return all the annotations. Their coordinates and dimensions must also be corrected; That's first of all  their `getRectangle` **Rect** but also, depending on the annotation in question, their `getInkList` **InkList** in case of **Ink** annotations, their `getQuadPoints` **QuadPoints** in case of text markup annotations, etc.Also don't forget coordinates of all kinds of destinations (of **Link** annotations, of **Outlines**, etc).